# Is npm react-bootstrap automatically scoped to a component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I am using react with react-bootstrap. My question now is, are react-bootstrap components automatically scoped to the component that you are using it in? Or am I asking a totally wrong question here? Because as I am aware that those bootstrap components are native react components, I am normally importing them like this:

```
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

but would it also be possible, to customize them or create own styles in a .css file (and overwrite other react-boostrap component styles) and import them into another component? I know they would not be react-bootstrap components then anymore, but would this be possible? E.g I could customize a button react-bootstrap component class in some .css file and import it in my module, would it overwrite native react-bootstrap classes?